# Javascript event listener overwrites another event listener

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation, addeventlistener

so I am trying to create a multilevel navigation for a mobile device and I am running into some issues. I am still learning javascript so please bare with me. Here is a link to the codepen:

https://codepen.io/maciekmat/pen/yLepYKq

So when you press the menu in the top right, a menu will open down. Then I would like to be able to go into sub categories. For example click Test Open, .active class will be assigned, and another menu slides in. Now I would like to have a go back button that essentially removes the .active class.

However what I think is happening, the event listener listens to the whole parent, and anywhere you click inside the subnavigation, it registers it as a click, and runs the .active class. When I click to go back, its like .active is removed and applied back instantly. Any help please?

I tried doing the event.currentEvent !== event.target if statement but had no luck

```js
const nav = document.getElementById('menuIcon')
const dropdown = document.getElementById('menuDropdown')

nav.addEventListener('click', function() {
    dropdown.classList.toggle('nav-is-toggled')
});

const grabNavLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.sub-nav-link');
const grabBackLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link.back');
const subNavLinks = Array.from(grabNavLinks);
const backLinks = Array.from(grabBackLinks);

for (let i = 0; i < subNavLinks.length; i++) {
  subNavLinks[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.querySelector('.sub-nav').classList.add('active');
  });
}

for (let i = 0; i < backLinks.length; i++) {
  backLinks[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.querySelector('.sub-nav').classList.remove('active');
  });
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;600;700&display=swap");
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Open sans", sans-serif;
  background: #F9F9F9;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a, p, h1, h2, h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul, li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background: white;
  padding: 24px 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}

.top-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.top-nav .logo {
  background: url("images/tcb-logo-brand.svg") no-repeat;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}
.top-nav .navigation {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 132px;
  height: 26px;
}
.top-nav .navigation .nav-item {
  width: 23px;
  height: 26px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
}
.top-nav .navigation .nav-item.menu {
  background-image: url("images/menu-icon.svg");
}
.top-nav .navigation .nav-item.notification {
  background-image: url("images/bell-icon.svg");
}
.top-nav .navigation .nav-item.my-account {
  background-image: url("images/acc-icon.svg");
}

.search {
  margin-top: 16px;
}
.search input[type=search] {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  background: #F6F6F6;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
  background-image: url("images/search-icon.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right 15px top 50%;
}
.search input[type=search]::placeholder {
  color: #B7B7B7;
}

span.nav-title {
  display: none;
}

nav.main-nav {
  width: 100%;
  background: #F6F6F6;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
nav.main-nav ul {
  padding-top: 2px;
  position: relative;
}
nav.main-nav li {
  list-style: none;
}
nav.main-nav a {
  color: #6D6D6D;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 18px 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E9E9E9;
}
nav.main-nav li.nav-link.arrow {
  background: url("images/right-arrow.svg") no-repeat;
  background-position: right 30px top 50%;
}
nav.main-nav ul.sub-nav {
  background: #cecece;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease;
}

.sub-nav-link > .sub-nav.active {
  transform: translateX(0);
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

nav.nav-is-toggled {
  position: static;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
    <header>
        <div class="top-nav">
            <div class="logo"></div>
            <div class="navigation">
                <div id="menuIcon" class="nav-item menu">test</div>
                <div class="nav-item notification"></div>
                <div class="nav-item my-account"><span class="nav-title">My Account</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="search">
            <input type="search" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search by store...">
        </div>
    </header>

    <nav id="menuDropdown" class="main-nav">
        <ul class="main-nav-ul">
            <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li class="nav-link arrow sub-nav-link"><a href="#">Test Open</a>
                <ul class="sub-nav">
                    <li class="nav-link back"><a href="#">Go Back</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li class="nav-link arrow sub-nav-link"><a href="#">Test Open</a>
                <ul class="sub-nav">
                    <li class="nav-link back"><a href="#">Go Back</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Test</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <script src="navigation.js"></script>
```

Comment: did this solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go read on event bubbling and how it bubbles through the DOM tree. However due to the way it passes from parent to child (that's it bubbles down the tree) you should call `event.stopPropagation();` So that the previous event doesnt bubble into the `backLinks` event listener.

This is what you should do

```
for (let i = 0; i < backLinks.length; i++) {
  backLinks[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    document.querySelector('.sub-nav').classList.remove('active');
  });
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much for your answer, I tried the above solution before but with your comments I realised it might have not been the best solution, thank you for pointing it out! I have used your above suggestion, and it works great, and I am currently reading more about event propagation and translating through the DOM.

The back button didnt work on both only on the top one, but i nested a for loop of an Array of all back buttons/subnavigations and applied remove class there. Works like a charm now! 

Would you say the above code, or the rest of it, looks ok? or a better approach ther?

Comment: @Mac it is ok, I would do it differently but i believe everyone has his/her process. The more experience you get the better your code composition but i see you already sticking to using `let` instead of `var` so that is a plus for you